# having Uncaught Error: near "(": syntax error when trying to run query

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

When I am trying to run this query i am getting an error which is mentioned below. i am assuming the error lies in my first line of query. which is not getting resolved. can anyone point out where i am wrong?

```
WITH processed_users 
 AS (SELECT LEFT(u.phone_country, 2) AS short_phone_country, 
            u.id 
     FROM   users u) 
    SELECT t.user_id, 
   t.merchant_country, 
   Sum(t.amount / fxr.rate / Power(10, cd.exponent)) AS amount 
   FROM   transactions t 
   JOIN fx_rates fx 
     ON ( fx.ccy = t.currency 
          AND fx.base_ccy = 'USD' ) x`
   JOIN currency_details cd 
     ON cd.currency = t.currency 
   JOIN processed_users pu 
     ON pu.id = t.user_id 
     WHERE  t.source = 'IA'
```

I am getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: You have a stray backtick. Plus `power()` is not a built in sqlite function; is this a user-defined one?

Comment: yes the `power()` is user-defined. where exactly the stray backtick is?

Comment: What is your SQLite version? CTEs were introduced in 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

i have found a bactric in your query and you need `SUBSTR` because left is not available at sqllite

```
WITH processed_users 
 AS (SELECT SUBSTR(u.phone_country,-length(u.phone_country), 2) AS short_phone_country, 
            u.id 
     FROM   users u
    ) 
    SELECT t.user_id, 
   t.merchant_country, 
   Sum(t.amount / fxr.rate / Power(10, cd.exponent)) AS amount 
   FROM   transactions t 
   JOIN fx_rates fx 
     ON ( fx.ccy = t.currency 
          AND fx.base_ccy = 'USD' ) x
   JOIN currency_details cd 
     ON cd.currency = t.currency 
   JOIN processed_users pu 
     ON pu.id = t.user_id 
     WHERE  t.source = 'IA'
```

I prefer to embrace `t.amount / fxr.rate / Power(10, cd.exponent)` line by parentesis

Comment: the error lies in one first line. where i have used AS in subquery. query is giving error on very first line.

Comment: @RaiAbdullah answer edited actually you need SUBSTR